# Ordenar cronologicamente data e horário VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber como eu faço para ordenar por data e hora por excel.
Seria 1 coluna de horario e outra de data. Ai minha dúvida é como ordeno os horarios cronologicamente sem afetar as datas??

Segue o exemplo de como eu gostaria que os dados ficassem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Exemplo:

Com estes dados de teste:

```
+------------+-------+
| 28/02/2012 | 10:00 |
| 19/02/2015 | 09:00 |
| 22/02/2015 | 04:32 |
| 01/03/2017 | 08:00 |
| 19/01/2018 | 01:00 |
| 19/01/2018 | 15:00 |
| 13/02/2018 | 09:00 |
| 16/02/2015 | 12:00 |
| 13/06/2013 | 15:00 |
| 13/06/2013 | 11:00 |
+------------+-------+
```

### Código

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim UltimaLinha As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
UltimaLinha = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With ws.Sort
 .SortFields.Clear
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C" & UltimaLinha), Order:=xlAscending
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1:D" & UltimaLinha), Order:=xlAscending
 .SetRange Range("C1:D" & UltimaLinha)
 .Header = xlNo
 .Apply
End With
```

### Resultado

```
+------------+-------+
| 28/02/2012 | 10:00 |
| 13/06/2013 | 11:00 |
| 13/06/2013 | 15:00 |
| 16/02/2015 | 12:00 |
| 19/02/2015 | 09:00 |
| 22/02/2015 | 04:32 |
| 01/03/2017 | 08:00 |
| 19/01/2018 | 01:00 |
| 19/01/2018 | 15:00 |
| 13/02/2018 | 09:00 |
+------------+-------+
```

Para mais informações sobre a última linha, verificar [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283358/encontrar-ultima-celula-preenchida-em-um-range/283555#283555)

## Explicação

### .SortField

O Método [.SortField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sortfield-object-excel) foi usado, em que a utilização é feita para ordenar os dados de acordo com campos de classificação.

A diferença do `.SortField` para o `.Sort` é que o `.Sort` é limitado em no máximo três campo, já o `.SortField` pode realizar em mais do que três. Neste caso só foram necessários dois, porém, é um código que é bom ser aprendido desta forma, pois pode atender a todas as necessidades.

### ws

`Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")`

Declara a Planilha de nome "Planilha1" como variável `ws`

### UltimaLinha

`UltimaLinha = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Retorna o número da última linha da Planilha `ws`

### SortField.Add

`.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C" & UltimaLinha), Order:=xlAscending`

Adiciona um Filtro de ordenação na coluna `C` da primeira linha até a última linha

### SetRange

`.SetRange Range("C1:D" & UltimaLinha)`

Estabelece o intervalo de filtro de ordenação de `C1` a `D & número da última linha`.

Comment: Nossa deu Certinho! Muito obrigado! Agora vou tentar entender o que o seu código diz (sou bem iniciante ^^)

Comment: Pronto, muito obrigado ^^

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função de classificação personalizada por níveis hierárquicos:

[image]