# Encontrar ultima célula preenchida em um range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

É possível encontrar a última célula preenchida em um `range` e colar um valor na próxima linha vazia abaixo?

Preciso de um código que faça a busca no range `("B5:B35")`. Usei o seguinte código, mas após a célula 35 eu tenho outras informações então os dados são colados em local errado

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B8,B11:B15")) Is
Nothing Then Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 2), Cells(Selection.Row,
4)).Select Selection.Copy

Worksheets("Cálculos").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1,
0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Última Célula de um intervalo

```
    Dim Calc As Worksheet
    Dim intervalo As Range
    Dim matriz As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set Calc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cálculos")
    Set intervalo = Calc.Range("A20:C30")
    matriz = intervalo

    For j = intervalo.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        For i = intervalo.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If matriz(i, j) <> "" Then
                MsgBox intervalo(i, j).Address
                GoTo sairLoop
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
sairLoop:
```

#### Última Linha de um intervalo numa Coluna

Por exemplo do intervalo de A10 até A30 se estiver preenchido somente até A26, retornará 26:

```
Dim Calc As Worksheet
Dim UltimaLinha As Long
Set Calc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cálculos")

With Calc.Range("A10:A30").CurrentRegion
     UltimaLinha = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
End With
```

#### Última Linha de uma Coluna

Para encontrar a última linha, há várias formas, mas a que EU mais utilizo é:

`UltimaLinha= Worksheets("Cálculos").Cells(Worksheets("Cálculos").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

ou

```
Dim Calc As Worksheet
Set Calc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cálculos")

With Calc
    UltimaLinha= .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

ou

```
Dim Calc As Worksheet
Set Calc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cálculos")
UltimaLinha= Calc.Cells(Calc.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

#### Última Linha da Planilha

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

#### Resultado:

Então a linha do seu código mudaria para:

`Worksheets("Cálculos").Cells(UltimaLinha, 2).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

ou

`Worksheets("Cálculos").Cells(UltimaLinha + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

> **Observação:** Declarar a UltimaLinha como Long (`Dim UltimaLinha As Long`), pois muitos tutoriais antigos utilizam o Integer, que possui 2 bytes e
>   o intervalo de     –32 768 a 32 767. Portanto, se a versão do Excel for
>   maior do que 2007, o programa irá parar após a linha 32767. Já o Long
>   possui 4 bytes e intervalo de -2 147 483 648 a 2 147 486 647. Em que o
>   Excel possui um limite de 1 048 576 linhas.