# Como "concatenar" múltiplos valores inseridos por um usuário na tabela em uma Msg box?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Vou tentar resumir o que estou tentando fazer:

Fiz um userform para que meu usuário insere dados que vão alimentar uma tabela, ele pode colocar "n" informações e a tabela vai se formando de acordo com o volume de dados que ele preencher.

Após isso, quando ele terminar e clicar em FIM, quero que outro userform abra na tela com uma frase concatenando os dados que foram inseridos, seguindo uma lógica pré determinada.

Por exemplo, após os inputs a planilha ficou assim:

[image]

O que eu quero é que meu próximo userform traga o seguinte concatenado:

'Teste' -x "1111|2|66","2222|2|77","3333|3,88","4444|3|99" -n

Os termos que preciso adicionar com & eu consigo, mas nao sei como concatenar desta maneira os valores de cada coluna seguindo a sequência e parando até o ponto em que não existir mais informação na planilha.

Outro detalhe seria ter essa separação por , entre cada concatenado

O trecho onde quero colocar o comando para concatenar isso está aqui:

```
Private Sub sair_click()
    Dim parse As String
    parse = "concatenado"
    Unload Me
    code.console = parse
    code.Show
End Sub
```

(depois que ele clica no botão FIM "sair" abre meu userform "code" com a variável "parse" que deve ter esse resultado concatenado.

---

Após utilizar a solução apresentada eu substituí o “sub ShowWithMessage” para a chamada do meu ultimo Userform, pois atendeu a demanda necessária (espera-se que meu user possa copiar o resultado para colar em outro local). Talvez seja algum erro que cometi, para ilustrar melhor, a sequencia esperada é o seguinte:

1º Userform: O usuário insere o título, após clicar em enter, outro userform abre;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2º Userform: O usuário insere as três informações necessárias para preencher as colunas da tabela quantas vezes necessário (Clicando em Enter após cada preenchimento). Ao terminar ele clica em FIM que traz o ultimo Userform com uma caixa de texto contendo o resultado concatenado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste exemplo simulei o caso onde apenas uma linha fosse inserida pelo usuário.

```
+---+------------------+----------------+-----------+
|   |        A         |       B        |     C     |
+---+------------------+----------------+-----------+
| 1 | Nome da Planilha | Teste'         |           |
| 2 | Node da Aula     | Tipo da Tarefa | Agrupador |
| 3 | "1111|           | 2|             | 66"       |
|   |                  |                |           |
+---+------------------+----------------+-----------+
```

3º Userform: Como dito acima o resultado final da inserção de apenas uma linha completa na tabela ficou desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O script do botão "FIM" está da seguinte maneira, utilizando a solução proposta neste tópico:

```
    Private Sub sair_click()
        Dim parse As String
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim UltimaLinhaPlanilha As Long, Linhas As Long, Colunas As Long
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ADAE")
        UltimaLinhaPlanilha = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        parse = ws.Range("B1") & " -x "

        For Linhas = 3 To UltimaLinhaPlanilha
            For Colunas = 1 To 3
                parse = parse & ws.Cells(Linhas, Colunas)
            Next Colunas
            If Linhas <> UltimaLinhaPlanilha Then parse = parse & ","
        Next Linhas
        parse = parse & " -n"
        Unload Me
        code.console = parse 'Aqui eu chamo o ultimo userform "code" com o que estará escrito dentro da caixa de texto "console" no caso a variável "parse"
        code.Show      
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Formulários

Pelo que entendi você possuirá dois formulários o `Userform1` e o `Userform2`

- No Userform1 há um botão que você clica para sair.
- No Userform2 a mensagem será exibida.

Portanto, para os testes, os seguintes formulários são criados:

Userform1 possui o o botão de nome `CommandButton1`:

[image: Userform1]

O Userform2 possui um Rótulo de nome `Label1`:

[image: Userform2]

## Dados

Com os dados na planilha (aba) de nome `Planilha1` desta maneira:

```
+---+------------------+----------------+-----------+
|   |        A         |       B        |     C     |
+---+------------------+----------------+-----------+
| 1 | Nome da Planilha | Teste'         |           |
| 2 | Node da Aula     | Tipo da Tarefa | Agrupador |
| 3 | "1111|           | 2|             | 66"       |
| 4 | "2222|           | 2|             | 77"       |
| 5 | "3333|           | 3|             | 88"       |
| 6 | "4444|           | 3|             | 99"       |
|   |                  |                |           |
+---+------------------+----------------+-----------+
```

## Código

Um outro formulário será usados para mostrar os dados, pois a MsgBox possui um limite de no máximo 1024 caracteres. E o OP pediu por formulário:

> O que eu quero é que meu próximo userform traga o seguinte concatenado:

O código para realizar isto é o seguinte:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim parse As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim UltimaLinhaPlanilha As Long, Linhas As Long, Colunas As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
    UltimaLinhaPlanilha = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    parse = ws.Range("B1") & " -x "

    For Linhas = 3 To UltimaLinhaPlanilha
        For Colunas = 1 To 3
            parse = parse & ws.Cells(Linhas, Colunas)
        Next Colunas
        If Linhas <> UltimaLinhaPlanilha Then parse = parse & ","
    Next Linhas
    parse = parse & " -n"
    ShowWithMessage parse
    Unload Me
End Sub

'https://stackoverflow.com/a/23313840/7690982
Public Sub ShowWithMessage(msg As String)
    UserForm2.Label1.Caption = msg
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

O código é inserido dentro de Userform1.

## Resultado

[image: ![Resultado]

## Explicação

Após o clique no botão o código dentro de `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` é executado. Em que a string `parse` é criada e a mensagem é chamada com o `Public Sub ShowWithMessage(msg As String)`

#### Declaração Planilha

`Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")`

#### Última Linha

A última linha da planilha é encontrada com `UltimaLinhaPlanilha = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count` e mais informações podem ser encontradas [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283358/75104)

#### String

A string parse é criada com a seguinte concatenação:

- Título é inserido com `parse = ws.Range("B1") & " -x "`
- Depois loops são realizados da Linha 3 até a última linha preenchida na planilha. Em cada linha o loop da coluna 1 ou A até a coluna 3 ou C, após o loop em todas as colunas, a vírgula é inserida. Cada loop insere os dados da planilha na string parse.
- Por último insere o " -n"

#### Call Sub

Por último o Sub é chamado com `ShowWithMessage parse`, em que a variável parse é inserida como variável de entrada do tipo String.

#### Sub ShowWithMessage

Primeiro altera a propriedade de Caption com a string inserida com `UserForm2.Label1.Caption = msg` e depois abre o Userform2.

Comment: Deu certo, ótima explicação! Agradeço o cuidado no trabalho de detalhar a explicação.

Comment: Depois de mais testes, me veio mais uma dúvida.. Funcionou normal para mais de 3 linhas preenchidas. Mas 2 ou 1 linha apenas, a vírgula aparece também. Por exemplo:

Teste' -x "1111|2|66",, -n  OU

Teste' -x "1111|2|66","2222|2|77", -n

Comment: Para mim não ocorreu este erro, você possui mais dados em outras colunas desta aba/planilha?

Comment: Eu editei meu post com os detalhes do que eu modifiquei e como é o ciclo completo do meu projeto pra ilustrar melhor o problema

Comment: @FelipeStenzel Realizei os testes e está dando certo no meu, talvez a última linha da planilha não seja a linha 3, porque há mais informações em outras colunas. Então ao invés de obter a última linha da planilha, tente obter a última linha da coluna A com: `UltimaLinhaPlanilha= ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. Pois parece que há algum valor na linha 5 e isto faz com que o loop seja realizado até o 5, mesmo quando é para ir até 3 ou 4.

Comment: Agora funcionou perfeitamente, acho que devia ser o botão da macro que coloquei pra iniciar o processo, mas com esse novo comando funcionou, mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda!