# Listagem em ordem cronologica | Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel-vba, microsoft-excel, userform

Boa tarde, como faço pra ordenar os horários cronologicamente sem afetar as datas no excel, usando Visual Basic?

Eu tenho uma planilha onde são salvos os cadastros que eu faço pelo VBA. Na coluna G ficam as 'Datas de Pagamento'. O que eu gostaria é que essas datas fossem ordenadas cronologicamente. Como exemplificado abaixo:

[image: A ideia é deixar ele assim]

Eu tentei criar um macro e reaproveitar o código base pra fazer minha listagem aparecer em ordem cronológica mas não deu certo.

Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("G2:G")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comecei a mexer com Visual Basic há apenas alguns dias, ainda sou iniciante. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Ordenar cronologicamente data e horário VBA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283268/ordenar-cronologicamente-data-e-hor%c3%a1rio-vba)

Comment: Pior que não cara, eu já tinha chegado a essa resposta antes. Mas obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá.

O problema está no range. Precisa definir qual é a área onde você quer ordenar.

No seu exemplo, os dados vão até a linha 8, logo o range é G2:G8:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort
    .SetRange Range("G2:G8")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Opa Erick, obrigado pela resposta. Eu entendi, mas coloquei  G2:G pra pegar os próximos itens, os que eu ainda não inseri. Tem uma forma correta de escolher um range preventivo?

Comment: Oi Gabriel. Tem sim, você pode usar esse contador: Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row (O 7 é a coluna G, contando da esquerda para a direita). 

Implementando fica assim: 

.SetRange Range("G1:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row)

Comment: O legal do VBA é que você pode fazer a mesma coisa de muitas formas, se o seu caso é só ordenar os dados, pode simplificar: Range("G1:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Comment: Opa Erick, com a sua ajuda consegui aqui. Obrigado pela paciência.